# Can PWM break a DC motor?

Tags: motor, pwm

I want to know if controlling the speed of a DC motor with PWM could break (burn out the DC motor. Sorry my English isn't that good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provided that the voltage specs of the motor are not violated, no. However, the inductance of the motor stands a very good chance of destroying the *switch* unless an appropriately-rated [flyback diode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_diode) is used.

Comment: I'm new to Arduino and electronics. I'm planning to use a H-bridge (l293d) with the dc motor, in the project nº 10 of the arduino projects book that comes with the arduino starter kit there is no flyback diode.

Comment: In another project of the book, where a MOSFET is used, I found the flyback diode, but the project that uses the l293d there is no diode.

Comment: The l293d has these diodes already inside the package.

Answer (score 0):

Providing that you send the appropriate voltage this shouldn't break your motor. The creator of Arduino suggest this way of driving motor on his book.
Source: Massimo Banzi's book : "getting started with arduino" : chapter 5 Advanced Input and Output.